# React native .env IOS bundling success but android(Emulator) bundling failed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, .env

I was trying to load the API key from .env to my app.js in this way, iOS Bundling was completed, but Android Bundling failed. This is in an expo environment.

Here is the `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module:react-native-dotenv",
        {
          moduleName: "@env",
          path: ".env",
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

And I imported in this way
import {TEST_KEY} from '@env'

But I get
iOS Bundling complete 39ms
Android Bundling failed 27ms
Unable to resolve "@env" from "App.js"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know what I want to say isn't a kind of solution, but sometimes giving up some troubles could be a solution. I guess this `react-native-dotenv` has got critical issues. So I prefer to use [`react-native-config`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config) instead.

Follow the example:

```
import Config from 'react-native-config';

console.log(Config.API_BASE_URL);

// The above line will log the API_BASE_URL from .env file.
```